# Mootools Request Object not letting me have '+' signs in my query string

Tags: javascript, mootools, request

I have the following Javascript/Mootools code:

```
var str = self.tI.get('value').replace(/\s/g,'+'),
    data = 'action=getplaces&str=' + str + '&latLng=' + $('coords').get('value'),
    r = new Request({
        url: 'action.php',
        method: 'get',
        link: 'cancel',
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            /* Do Stuff */
        }
    }).send(data);
console.log(str);
```

On the first line I replace any spaces with + signs. When I log the value of str in the console, I get the appropriate value (ie: 'blabla+bla')

However, when I send the request, my request fails. If I look at the headers and the query string, the + sign is simply replaced again with a space (ie: 'blabla bla')

What's up with that? And is there a way around it?

Comment: Try to urlencode the str like this: `str = encodeURIComponent(str);`. Oh, and one more thing, why would you replace spaces with "+"? Why not just encode the spaces with uri-encoding too?

Comment: One more thing, you say you look at the request headders. Do you do this from the server or the client? If it's on the server, it might just mean that the server has parsed the +'s as spaces (which I know can happen in some cases).

Comment: @Alxandr: Client side. Just the Chrome / Firefox network panel.

Comment: Check it server side as well. It might be that the Firebug panel shows the unparsed string. At least in the request url there are plusses when I try your code.

Comment: you can let it do it for you auto. include `data: { action: "blah",str: str, foo: $("bar").get("value") }` in the Request options and just do .send();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody wondering, my problem ended up being server side. Once the data got to the server side, I was trying to incorporate it in another URL but the server had already parsed the %20 and the +'s to spaces. So had to do some string manipulation on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape plus as it's a reserved character in HTML Url's
replace it with `&#43;`